# Multiclass Classification Task - Performance on Each Class Compared to Chance?

Tags: classification, class-imbalance, performance

As a part of a classification task, a classifier has decided whether different books belong to class A, B or C (which are imbalanced) by looking at certain feature of the book.

I have calculated different classification performance metrics (e.g. accuracy, (macro and micro) recall, precision, f1, etc.

I have also assessed the overall performance of the classifier compared to chance using kappa and MCC.

What I want now is the performance on each class (A,B,C) in relation to chance.

Up to now I know that the performance of the classifier overall is not better than chance. I would like to know whether:

the performance of the classifier on class A is better than chance.
the performance of the classifier on class B is better than chance.
the performance of the classifier on class C is better than chance.
Does it make sense to run individual kappa/MCC for each of the classes?